# ERROR: syntax error at or near "on" LINE 2: FROM reviews GROUP BY product_id

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

how to i translate this into ruby on rails syntax ?

```
@products = Product.select('* FROM products p inner join (SELECT product_id, AVG(rating) as avg_rating
FROM reviews GROUP BY product_id) as x on p.id = x.product_id ORDER BY x.avg_rating DESC')
```

> error: FROM" LINE 2: ...on p.id = x.product_id ORDER BY x.avg_rating
> DESC FROM "prod... ^

Comment: Please include the SQL statements that is actually executed in the database.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use subquery like this:

```rb
 Product.joins(
   "INNER JOIN (#{Review.select('product_id, AVG(rating) AS avg_rating').group('product_id').to_sql}) AS reviews ON reviews.product_id = products.id"
 ).order('reviews.avg_rating DESC')
```

Or you can use `Arel`

```rb
products = Product.arel_table
reviews = Review.arel_table

subquery = reviews.project(:product_id, reviews[:rating].average).group(:product_id).as('reviews')

products.join(subquery).on(subquery[:product_id].eq(products[:id])).order(reviews[:rating].average.desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below:

```rb
Product.joins("INNER JOIN ((SELECT product_id, AVG(rating) as avg_rating FROM reviews GROUP BY product_id) as x on products.id = x.product_id)")
       .order("x.avg_rating DESC")
```